# just another evil hangman quesiton

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

Yes, this is related to homework and no I'm not looking for you to code it for me just a point in the right direction.

I'm trying to implement a `linked list` to represent the list of the current possible words in the list after the user has guessed a letter.

Currently I am doing the following to read in the lenght of the word the player wants to guess upon and then appending all possible words to the linked list.

However, I fail to see how I could continually update the linked list to compute the biggest word family and print the current word progress

(Ex. the dashed word with all of the current letters the user has guessed in there).

Mainly having problems because I fail to fully understand how linked lists work and how to implement them in my programs.

How I'm making the initial linked list of all possible words.

```
 def make_ll(self):
    linked_list = ll.LinkedList()
    print(linked_list)
    for word in self.init_list:
        if len(word) == int(self.word_length):
            linked_list.append(str(word))
    self.linked_list = linked_list

def init_family(self, guess):

    self.dictionary = {}
    cursor = self.linked_list.head
    while cursor != None:
    word = cursor.data
    cursor = cursor.next
    word = self.make_families(word, guess)

def make_families(self, word, guess):
    count = 0
    new_word = ""
    for c in word:

        if guess == c:
            count += 1
        else:
            new_word = word.replace(c, "-")

    if count == 0:
        self.linked_list.delete(word)

    key = new_word
    if key not in self.dictionary:
        self.dictionary[key] = []
    self.dictionary[key].append(word)
    max = max(self.dictionary.values(), key = len)
    new_linked_list = ll.linked_list
    for word in max:
        new_linked_list.append(word)
    self.linked_list = new_linked_list



return word
```

Comment: A linked list is pretty easy to understand. It is basically just a node (a node is a "point" in the list that may contain data) that has a reference to the next node, and that node has the reference to the next, etc.. Usually, this reference will be a pointer. In Python it's done a little differently, but the concept is the same.

However, I do not think a linked list would be the best data structure for your problem. There is a data structure that is commonly used for words called a Trie, which closely resembles a tree. Do you have to use a linked list?

Comment: Neither do I know how to do this with a dictionary but since we are learning data structures I do have to use a linked list and no I've never heard of that only thing we have learned are queues, stacks, and linked list so far.

Comment: Trie isn't really super common, don't worry if you haven't heard about it. Can you pick the problem you are working on, or do you have to solve the problem above with a linked list? The only way I can see to do this with a linked list would not have great runtime. I'm not an expert, but you'd have to go through the entire list each time you did an update replacing the characters you'd like to replace.

Comment: Yes it has to be done that way and I don't think runtime is an issue mostly just for learning the data structure I assume I thought it would be something along those lines but fail to see how these would be implemented

Comment: Can you update with what you are trying to do and how it fails/what it does instead? The code snippet you posted seems to initialize a linked list correctly. Is your problem in the implementation of a linked list? If so post what you have and where exactly you need help. Or don't you understand how a linked list works? If so, post what exactly is unclear.

Comment: I think Skeletor is having a problem understanding how linked lists work, as well as how to traverse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skeletor,

This can be done using a Linked List, but it is not the optimal solution.

You can think of a Linked List as a bunch of train cars. Each car does two things:

1) It holds something (in programming, this is the `data` - in your case it is a word).

2) It connects to other cars (in programming this is usually something called a `pointer`).

Both of these things are a part of the train car. In Linked Lists, this is called the `node`.

```
 Node1      Node2      Node3
 -----      -----      -----
|Data1| -> |Data2| -> |Data3|
 -----      -----      -----
```

There are a few operations you can perform on train cars:

1) You can add a new car anywhere if you adjust the connectors appropriately.

2) You can walk through cars, depending on the rules for traffic, and look at the data inside.

3) Being in a car let's you easily find the next: you just have to exit and board the next car.

Linked lists have these same rules:

1) They allow you to add a node anywhere you like, but you have to adjust the references to the node (the pointers.)

2) When you're looking at the node you can easily access the data.

3) You can access the next node easily by looking at that node's reference. If you have a doubly linked list, you can look at both the previous and next node.

Most confusion understanding linked lists is the `linked` part of the definition. Like I mentioned, this is usually a pointer. To understand how that works you'll have to understand pointers, however, you can still understand linked lists by walking through one yourself.

First, let's define our train car(or our node):

```
class TrainCar:
    def __init__(self, data):
        # this is the contents of our train car
        self.data = data
        # This is the reference to the next node, or the train car's connector.
        # Accessing it gets you the next TrainCar, if one exists
        self.next_car = None
```

Once you get this, it already starts to fall into place. Basically you have a bunch of nodes with each one referencing the next node! All that's left to do is to implement our operations:

```
# making a new linked list
class Train:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head_car = None

    def add_car(self, data):
        # make new car/node
        new_car = TrainCar()
        # add our data to the new car as desired
        new_car.data = data

        # This is where the magic happens! We're updating the reference inside
        # the node we just made to point to the last car we were on.
        # We are just adding a new car to the end of the train.
        new_car.next_car = self.head_car

        # Now we're setting the head car to be the one we just made!
        self.head_car = new_car
```

Now, other operations - such as traversing the linked list and deleting nodes - are left to you.